# Question about (stochastic parallel-gradient descent) SPGD and (simultaneous perturbation stochastic approximation) SPSA

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, stochastic-differential-equations

I wonder if someone could shed some light on this. I'm curious if stochastic parallel-gradient descent and simultaneous perturbation stochastic approximation refer to the same optimization techniques.

Comment: They do appear to be based on basically the same idea, developed and named by different authors. Of course, the devil is in the details, and specific detailed implementations might differ in significant ways, regardless of what the algorithm is called..

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, thanks. I read a few paper on this but I'm not clear the fine difference